# Cropping And Showing Image Squared and non squared image like Instagram

Tags: image, instagram, crop

Hello people I am very much in need of help as i want to  build similar functionality like Instagram. I have to crop the image same as Instagram does and want to show button which shows Image like Zoomed one pic  and original one pic. I have refereed [this link but I am not getting exactly what i want.enter link description here](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma) 
I Want something like this[image]